# How to best find the time difference between a desired sequence of events?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, datetime

Say I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Time', 'Event'])
df.Time = ['06:15.2', '06:15.2', '06:45.3', '43:26.8', '43:26.8', '43:57.9', '27:30.0', '27:31.1', '27:31.1', '27:31.1', '27:31.1', '32:41.0', '10:22.6', '10:22.6', '10:54.7', '11:30.3', '11:30.3']
df.Event = ['login', 'other', 'logout', 'login', 'other', 'logout', 'login', 'other', 'other', 'login', 'logout', 'logout', 'login', 'other', 'logout', 'login', 'other']
```

[image]

I want to find the time difference between a login and the logout that comes immediately after the login. That is, if there are multiple logins and then one logout, I want to find the time difference between the last login and the logout.

My attempt to do this is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime

diff = np.zeros(len(df))

for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.Event[i]=='login':
        for j in range(len(df[i:])):
            if df.Event[j]=='logout':
                diff[j] = (datetime.datetime.strptime(df.Time[j], '%M:%S.%f') - datetime.datetime.strptime(df.Time[i], '%M:%S.%f'))/ datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=1)
                
df['Diff'] = diff
df
```

But it doesn't produce the right result:

[image]

The correct result should be: the non-zero numbers in the `Diff` column should be 30.1, 31.1, 0.0, 0.0 (not sure how to handle this case, as this logout comes after a logout...considering pairwise logins and logouts would be adding another level of complexity), 32.1

Is there any Pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Please also include the correct result

Comment: Your column `Time` contains strings? Is this correct? Will all time points be within one day? And is there a reason for not using pandas functionality instead of slower loops?

Comment: @timgeb ok, done

Comment: @Mr.T Yes, `Time` contains strings, as otherwise I could not find a simple way to write the dataframe values here. In the real dataset, the time points extend over a few months. And I'm using loops as I don't know the pandas functionality that would do this faster.

Comment: a "time" like `'43:26.8'` looks more like a ***duration*** to me - can you clarify?

Comment: @FObersteiner The times are in the following format: `HH:MM:SS.MS`. For some reason, the sample data I copied did not have the `HH` component; they only contain the `MM:SS.MS` part.

Comment: ok that still does not make things easier I suspect; what happens if login and logout take place on different dates?

Comment: May I ask why the time `"10:22.6"` comes after `"32:41.0"`? Is there supposed to be an `HH` value before the `"10:22.6"` value? Otherwise those times make no sense.

Comment: @AJH Yes, there's supposed to be a `HH` component before, like I mentioned above.

Comment: @FObersteiner Yes, that is a challenge. In the real dataset, from what I understand, not each and every login and logout are observed. Only if the user legitimately logs out of the system, this DB logs that record as a logout - so, for instance, if the user shuts down the system, that won't be recorded as a logout, but even so when they login the next time, it will be recorded as a login. So, I don't really know how to handle this scenario, but for now I just need something reasonable to start my analysis with.

Comment: @Kristada673 Did you ever come up with a good solution? If so could you post it?

Answer (score 1):

I've got some very long and inefficient code, but it works. The first function is used later to turn times into the string format you want. The `Times` and `Events` columns are turned into lists and then list comprehension is done to turn the time strings into minutes.

```
# str is in HH:MM:SS.MS format. this_time is in minutes.
def convert_time_to_str(this_time):

    seconds = (this_time % 1)*60
    ms = int(round((seconds % 1) * 1000, 0))
    seconds = int(seconds // 1)
    
    if this_time < 1:
        return str(seconds) + "." + str(ms)
        
    minutes = this_time % 1    
    hours = int(minutes // 60)
    minutes = int(minutes - hours*60)
    
    if minutes < 60:
        return str(minutes) + ":" + str(seconds) + "." + str(ms)
    else:
        return str(hours) + ":" + str(minutes) + ":" + str(seconds) + "." + str(ms)

times_list = df["Time"].tolist()
events = df["Event"].tolist()
times = []

# turning times_list into numbers (in terms of minutes).
for i in range(len(times_list)):
        
    this_time_str = times_list[i]
    this_time_split = this_time_str.split(":")
    
    s, ms = this_time_split[-1].split(".")
    
    if len(this_time_split) == 2:
        h = 0
        m = int(this_time_split[0])
    else:
        h = int(this_time_split[0])
        m = int(this_time_split[1])
         
    # times are in terms of minutes, since that seems to be the relevant scale in your case.
    this_time = int(h)*60 + int(m) + int(s)/60 + int(ms)/(60*1000)
    times.append(this_time)

# Finding time differences between login and logout.
final_time_diffs = [0]*len(events)
for i in range(1, len(events)):
    
    # iterate through rows corresponding to a logout.
    if events[i] == "logout":
        
        # j is how many indices before i (the logout row) the closest login is.
        last_login_idx = ""
        j = 1
        found_login = False
        
        while last_login_idx == "" and j <= i:
            previous_event = events[i-j]

            # If previous event was a logout, ignore this entire logout row.
            if previous_event == "logout":
                break
            elif previous_event == "login":
                last_login_idx = i - j
                found_login = True
                break
            j += 1
        
        # Find the time_diff between logout and closest previous login.
        if found_login:
            this_time_diff = times[i] - times[last_login_idx]
            this_time_diff_str = convert_time_to_str(this_time_diff)
            final_time_diffs[i] = this_time_diff_str
        else:
            final_time_diffs[i] = 0

# Name this column whatever you want; main thing is that it'll contain the time differences between login and logout. If there are 2 logouts in a row, the 2nd logout will have time_diff 0.
df["TimeDiffs"] = final_time_diffs
```

I haven't tested whether the code can put up with hours values in the `Times` column, but theoretically, it should. It cannot deal with times rolling over to the next day, so be aware! Also, if the hour values are very large, this code will unnecessarily eat up memory just to store the large times, since times are in terms of minutes; in that case, I'd advise working in chunks and subtracting a certain number of hours from all the times in question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Time', 'Event'])
df.Time = ['06:15.2', '06:15.2', '06:45.3', '43:26.8', '43:26.8', '43:57.9', '27:30.0', '27:31.1', '27:31.1', '27:31.1', '27:31.1', '32:41.0', '10:22.6', '10:22.6', '10:54.7', '11:30.3', '11:30.3']
df.Event = ['login', 'other', 'logout', 'login', 'other', 'logout', 'login', 'other', 'other', 'login', 'logout', 'logout', 'login', 'other', 'logout', 'login', 'other']

df["Time"] = df["Time"].apply(lambda x : int(x[0:2])*60 + float(x[3:]))
df["Time1"] = df["Time"].shift(1).fillna(0)
df1 = df[df["Event"].isin(["logout","login"])]
df1["Event1"] = df1["Event"].shift(1).fillna(0)

df2 = df1[(df1["Event"] == "logout") & (df1["Event1"] == "login")].assign( Duration = df1["Time"] - df1["Time1"])
df.merge(df2, how = "left").drop(["Time1","Event1"], axis = 1).fillna(0)
```

Here is the output :

```
Out[53]: 
      Time   Event  Duration
0    375.2   login       0.0
1    375.2   other       0.0
2    405.3  logout      30.1
3   2606.8   login       0.0
4   2606.8   other       0.0
5   2637.9  logout      31.1
6   1650.0   login       0.0
7   1651.1   other       0.0
8   1651.1   other       0.0
9   1651.1   login       0.0
10  1651.1  logout       0.0
11  1961.0  logout       0.0
12   622.6   login       0.0
13   622.6   other       0.0
14   654.7  logout      32.1
15   690.3   login       0.0
16   690.3   other       0.0
```